# Do we have any functionality in Quickblox javascript to retrive sorting of dialogs on the basis of unread messages in it

Tags: javascript, quickblox

Do we have any functionality in Quickblox javascript to retrive sorting of dialogs on the basis of unread messages in it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.